# C#, SQL Server - Connecting to local server without specifying data source

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I am writing a c# application. I connect to a backend SQL Server for some processing. However I hit into a weird issue today. This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=true");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();

    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
    Console.Read();
}
```

I haven’t given the server name in the Connection String, but still it connects to my local database and retrieves the required data. I am wondering how. Is the default data source set to local machine? Does “Integrated Security=true” have something to do with this?

Can someone explain this?

Thanks,
Sornakumar S

Comment: Perhaps the default Data Source is (local) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/09/19/understanding-data-source-local-in-sql-server-connection-strings.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the docs on ConnectionString on MSDN you could find this information

> To connect to a local computer, specify "(local)" for the server. If a
>   server name is not specified,  a connection will be attempted to the
>   default instance on the local computer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Integrated Security means that it uses the current user's username and password to connect to the local SQL Server instance.. 
Without that, you would have had to specify the specific server, username and password. 
 
By the way, do not use it like that on the production server as you'll likely encounter an error. Use the web.config file for all database settings. 
 
Hope this helps.