# how to return all values when textbox is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, textbox

I have a textbox [DepartureRunwayTextBox] binding with one column [DepartureRunway]. I want to retrieve all values in GridView if the textbox is empty. I set ConvertEmptyStringToNull to false and tried CancelSelectOnNullParameter on true and false, and it doesn't work the way that I want. Please let me know how can I fix this.

**Aspx**

```
<asp:Label ID="DepartureRunwayLabel" runat="server" Text="Departure Runway" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="DepartureRunwayTextBox" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DepartureRunwaySqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Departure Runway] AS Departure_Runway FROM [Movement]" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="True"></asp:SqlDataSource>


    ...

<asp:Panel ID="GridViewPanel" runat="server">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="AircraftID" DataSourceID="GridViewDataSource" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" ShowFooter="True" Visible="False">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
    ...
```

**Aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ATOMS2._0
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView.Visible = true;
        }

        protected void GridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519813/c-sql-server-connecting-to-local-server-without-specifying-data-source

Comment: I solved the problem based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564536/how-to-get-a-gridview-to-show-all-table-rows-when-no-text-is-entered-in-a-depend